# Slow MySQL Query on compare

Tags: mysql

I have what seems like a simple issue but am struggling. I have 2 tables as below.

table 1 has room events and times (seconds)
table 2 has room access times (seconds)and name of person

For every row in table 1 I want to output the last person to enter the room but only if they entered the room in the last 5 minutes

time is the primary index for both tables

example of table 1 (events)

```
|time      |event|
|1294427839|poff |
|1294427939|pofn |
|1294428839|poff |
```

example of table 2 (entries)

```
|time      |name|
|1294427829|tpeters |
|1294427929|jsmith |
|1294428829|abeach |
```

table 1 has about 5,000 rows, table 2 about 300,000
I'm currently using the following query but it is taking minutes to complete. Could someone please adivse what I am doing wrong.

```
select (SELECT name FROM entries entries WHERE entries.time > events.time-300 and  entries.time < events.time order by entries.time desc limit 1) from events events
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Added more detail:

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE        TABLE    TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY     KEY_LEN     ROWS    FILTERED    EXTRA
1   PRIMARY            events   index                   PRIMARY 8           3       100     Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY entries  index   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 8           1       300     Using where
```

CREATE TABLE events (
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE entries (
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`time`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

Comment: Show `EXPLAIN` and both table structures. PS: rewrite query using `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT name, ev_time, en_time
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    IF(events.time = @last_time, 0, 1) AS last,
    @last_time := events.time AS ev_time,
    entries.time AS en_time
  FROM events
  LEFT JOIN entries ON (entries.time BETWEEN events.time-300 AND events.time)
  ORDER BY events.time, entries.time
) as tmp
WHERE last = 1
```

tested it at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96e30/2/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. A couple of issues, firstly I made a mistake, my query should have read 'order by entries.time' which I've now corrected above - sqlfiddle should return tpeters, jsmith, abeach. But secondly this doesn't actually seem any quicker to execute, it still takes about a minute, would you expect this on a table of my size? it seems very slow

Comment: as your Explain says its using `PRIMARY` in both case, and both is the type `index`, it not mutch you can do to optimize it as it is, if you going to use the query ofen, it may help to add a column to the `events` named `closest_entry`, and populate it before running the query, then you left join using that column as `equal_reference` insted of `range`